# How to unbind Facebox?

Tags: jquery, facebox

I have an anchor like below

```
<a href='...' rel='facebox'>..</a>
```

and use facebox like

```
$('#...').facebox();
```

But I need to unbind facebox() event dynamically, I tried the two ways as follows

```
$('#..').unbind('facebox'); 
$('#..').unbind('keydown.facebox');
```

But both don't work.

Who can help me out... ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `rel` attribute? I've not worked with the Facebox plug-in, but I'd assume the `rel` is used for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#...').unbind('click.facebox');
```

The [source code](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox/blob/master/src/facebox.js#L156) indicates that this is the name of the actual click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#..').unbind('.facebox');
```

(*notice the `.`*) this will unbind all events in the facebox namespace. (*which is what the facebox uses*)

Comment: this doesn't work.. I tried unbind('click') is okay. facebox bind facebox() to clickeventhandler.